# What are the little triangles for in the CSS sprite in SO

Tags: support, voting, design, sprites

I mean the little triangles under the big ones (the normal upvote/downvote).

[image]

<sup>[*link to image](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=2)</sup>

Are they for mods or something? Just curious.

I can't believe nobody knows, I will retag as <kbd>bug</kbd> then ;)

Thanks!

Comment: @waiwai933 thanks for the retag though I though curiosity was funny :P

Comment: I want to add that bot @waiwai933 and @Grace Note though it might be the arrows for voting tags (which in fact they might be) but the thing is that the on mode for those is black!

Comment: @Trufa Specifically they were talking about voting on tag synonyms, but those are a [separate sprite](http://stackoverflow.com/content/img/minivote.gif)

Comment: Maybe some mobile version (just wildly guessing here)

Comment: How about the two + signs?

Comment: huh? i dont get what arrows you mean...

Comment: @Johannes See the normal up and down vote arrows, below them, there are two small ones, I'll draw a circle around them later when I have time.

Comment: Amazing how dust collects :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question actually came up the other night when [Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) was looking at old sprite maps, they're no longer used, and will likely be removed in the future.

Comment: By any chance, do you know what they were used for?

Comment: @waiwai933 - I do not, we couldn't remember, possibly the original up/down for....something, I'm sure *someone* can recall...

Comment: No wonder nobody knew! Thank you very much!